# WCF service asynch / synch

Tags: mysql, wcf

I am new to WCF, I am using it to access MySql in silverlight application.
I have something simple like this:

> [OperationContract]
>           public List GetPolitics()
>           {
>               return _registrationData.GetPolitics();
>           }

where RegistrationData is a .NET assembly that communicates with the MySql using MySqlConnection.

My question is, the WCF creates Async operations by default, is there a way to have a synchronous operation that blocks on the call while the DB is being fetched ? if so how ?

Comment: How are you generating the client code? Is this a Silverlight client or basic .NET?

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that according to your code, you have already used the synchronized operation. If you want to provide async operation, you need to provide a pair of method: BeginXXX, EndXXX. Please read this: [Synchronous and Asynchronous Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx)

And what do you mean by blocking the call? do you want to block the thread on server side?

Comment: Well, when I compile the service and try to use it on the client side, I see the following:
GetPoliticsCompleted which is a delegate that I have to register for, and the call: GetPoliticsAsync(); the results comes in the delegate rather than waiting on GetPoliticsAsync() , GetPoliticsAsync is a void method